# How to Get an ID from a booking page and show it into admin after submitting form against that ID?

Tags: php, mysql

i'm setting up a booking info page where i have to submit a persons info on a specific tour package after the user click on booking button i.e

`<a href="booking_info.php?id='.$row['pid'].'">`Book Now

i get that package ID through this url, now after sending the user to booking info page i have made a query to get the user info and also that specific packageID after submission the info i dont receive the packageID and it says undefined index,

i have taken the packageID through a GET req from package page but the value does not pass to booking_info page.

booking_info.php

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $the_package_id = $_GET['pid'];
 $fname = $_POST['fname'];
 $lname = $_POST['lname'];
 $query="INSERT INTO 
 package_booking(pid,fname,lname,nationality,phone_number)";
 $query .= 
"VALUES($the_package_id,'$fname','$lname','$nationality','$phone_number')";
```

below is the query in the package.php where i need to click the book-Now button on that specific package

```
if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
 $the_package_id = $_GET['pid'];
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM package WHERE pid = $the_package_id ";
```

i want to submit user info along with the packageID into database so that i make sure that user have opted for that specific package.

Comment: So in your html link you call it `?id=` and in your PHP you ask for `$_GET['pid']`.. Change it to `$_GET['id']` (or the link to `?pid=`) and it should work. :) Play around with `print_r($_GET);` and `print_r($_POST);` in your code and you can see what is in the post/get arrays.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: You're composing queries, but are you running them? Defining a variable called `$query` doesn't actually do anything. This is why I suggest supplying queries directly to the database driver, not using intermediate variables. It's way harder to forget to execute that way.

Comment: corrected the link now passing the id as it was pid, now what i dont get is the pid to my DB as i submit the form all the form data is submitted but tried sending the pid i got stuck, should i get the pid as a hidden value in the form in order to store the packageID in db,

Answer (score 0):

I think you GET the wrong pid instead you must get id
try   `$_GET['id'];` instead `$_GET['pid']` in your code